# Creating a background process in java

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I want to create a background process that will be running 24*7 in the background with a unique name/identifier so that I can get reference to that process and kill that when I like. That process will perform some task as well like locking a file database.
Can I get some idea/code on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Timeline you could implement it like this this will fire an event every second inside its own thread

```
Timeline updater;
Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
    updater = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),(event -> checkLocked())));
    updater.setCycleCount(INDEFINITE);
    updater.play();
});
thread.start();
```

You can also stop this from running by using the command

```
updater.stop();
```

Comment: But i want it to be a continuous process and also want access to the object from other java code

Comment: What do you mean continuous you can change the time of how fast the event is fired

Comment: I suppose you could put it in a while loop

Comment: Will this thread be alive when its parent process is stopped? I think not. And how to refrence this timeline from any other java code/thread

Comment: I didn't put it inside any parent process

Comment: Ok thanks... I will try this approach and will let you know if it solves my case

Comment: Possibly make it static if necessary